# Magento 2: Is there any certification for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, ceritification

Is there any certification available for Magento 2 like we have for Magento1 ??

Comment: MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED SOLUTION SPECIALIST (BETA EXAM) is from August 14th to August 25th, 2017

- This Beta exam will be limited to 200 registrants.

- exam at a discounted rate of $130

- 150 Multiple Choice items/180 minutes to complete the exam

- All questions are valid for Magento Community Edition (2.0.x/2.1.x) and Magento Enterprise Edition (2..0.x/2.1.x).


Register fast as this Beta exam will be limited to 200 registrants.

Link : https://u.magento.com/certification-magento2-solution-specialist-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For magento 2 as of now there is no certification avaialable Except (**Trained Solution Parnter for magento2** Programm )

Refer this thread for more details - https://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/Magento-2-certification-exams/td-p/176

Refer this link for available certification im Magento - https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification

For more details about Trained Solution Partner refer this link - https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/look-magento-2-trained-solution-partners

Comment: Developer certification is released https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer#.Wp0lZnV97CI

Answer (score 0):

The full Magento 2 certification won't happen until after everyone has real-world experience with Magento 2, as it's based on that real-world experience that none of us have yet.

You can get more Information from Here : [Magento 2 certification exams](https://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/Magento-2-certification-exams/m-p/207#M36)